# AngularUI view not updating after model changes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Beginner question on AngularUI updating a view after the model changes.  I have a list of recipes and each recipe has a list ingredients.  After a $http GET for ingredients, my nested loop isn't updating.  Because other ng-repeat posts aren't helping I'm wondering if this is my AngularUI (UI) code.

How should subviews get updated after model changes?  Is a scope trigger needed?

**index.html:**

```
<body>
    <div ui-view></div>
    ....
    #Outer
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="front.html">
        <div ng-repeat="search in searches" ng-class="{starred: search.isStarred, active: search.isActive, editing: search.isediting}" class="row">
            <ng-include src="'grid.html'"></ng-include>
    ....
    #Inner 
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="grid.html">
        <ng-repeat="item in search">
        <!--   item in $scope.searches[$index].results -->
        <!--   item in $parent[$index].results -->
            <li>{{item.searchId}}</li>
            <!--<ng-include src="'image-item.html'"></ng-include>-->
```

**app.js:**

```
angular.module('tycho', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'tychoControllers', 'tychoDirectives', 'tychoServices'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/front");

$stateProvider
.state('front', {
    url: "/front",
    controller: 'tychoController',
    templateUrl: 'front.html'
})
```

**controllers.js:**

```
var controllers = angular.module('tychoControllers', []);
controllers.controller('tychoController', 
['$scope', '$filter', 'tychoStorage', 'tychoCapi', 'capiSearch', '$http', '$timeout', 
function tychoController(
$scope, $filter, tychoStorage, tychoCapi, capiSearch, $http, $timeout) 
{

var searches = $scope.searches = tychoStorage.getSearches();
$scope.capi = new tychoCapi();
//.....

$scope.$watch('searches', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.searchCount = searches.length;
    $scope.starredCount = $filter('filter')(searches, { starred: true }).length;
    $scope.completedCount = searches.length - $scope.starredCount;

    if (newValue !== oldValue) { // This prevents unneeded calls to the local storage
        tychoStorage.putSearches(searches);
    }
}, true);

$scope.runSearch = function (search) {
    capiSearch.getResults(search).then(function (data) {
        // fix for $$digest busy
        $timeout(function () {
            var i = $scope.searches.indexOf(search);
            if (i > -1 && data.Results && data.Results.length) {
                var arr = $scope.searches[i].results || []; 
                $scope.searches[i].results = arr.concat(data.Results);
                console.log('appending to', $scope.searches[i])
            }
        });
    });
};
```

The app is needs to update $scope.searches[ n ].results=.... in a controller and have the view (view's nested repeat) update too.  I feel like scope is wrong.

Comment: Is `#Inner` your '`front-section.html`' view?  Do you have a separate controller?  Can you post more of your document structure including the tags with `ng-app` and `ng-controller` on them?  If you're using the same controller you are probably having `$scope.searches` set on both the parent and child scopes, so when you update wone with 'runSearch` it will not update the other.

Comment: Updated source code to include more.  (and made naming more clear)  The controller shouldn't have scope problems because functions reference $scope.

Comment: You have a scope and controller (what type?) on the outside, your view has a separate scope and uses the `tychoController` as specified in your route, and your `grid.html` in the `ng-include` will have a separate scope as well although it looks like it won't have its own controller.  Use angularjs-batarang chrome extension to help debug them.  If you are re-using tychoController, it will set a different value for 'searches' in each scope and changing one will not affect the other.

Comment: That sounds right and like scope, ie the inner ng-repeat isn't notified or updated. Not sure how to resolve this but I'll try the debugger..

Answer (score 0):

Try above code in `subview`:

```
<ng-repeat="item in search.results as search in searches">
    <li>{{item.searchId}}</li>
    <!--<ng-include src="'search-grid-item.html'"></ng-include>-->
</ng-repeat>
```

Comment: I need model changes, the `$scope.searches[n].results` array, to update the view. Changing the layout won't work.

Comment: Then i think you can  try loop on $scope.search to get the results and then push results into array.

Comment: Tried this loop style without luck although, the UI needs more flexibility and styling around the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [Alexand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/475522/alexandru-badiu) for pointing out a tag issue.  Changing code from `<ng-repeat...` to `<div ng-repeat="item in search.results...`  allowed $scope updates to work from the controller.  Awesomeness.